# SignalR Implementation as network security bypass?

Tags: c#, networking, signalr

I have a network level, `network_1` that has outbound only access to `network_2`. `network_2` only has inbound access from `network_1` and no outbound access at all to anything (I don't control this access restriction).

I need to transfer data to `network_1` from `network_2`. If I open a connection using something like signalR, can I technically transmit data from `network_2` down to `network_1`? Considering something like this allows bidirectional communication and I have that one-way path from `N1` to `N2`, would this workaround be feasible?

Comment: Since HTTP uses TCP, which requires bidirectional communication to set up a connection, Then having one-way communication will not even work.

Comment: not a lot of context given here, but why not use TCP? just open a socket from network1 into network2

Comment: In fact, if you control the computers on each side, then you could setup a VPN